# 2d String Array NullPointerException (java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, multidimensional-array

I am currently creating a java application in which I have a 2d array which I want to get some data into.

I am creating the 2d array as such

```
String[][] addressData;
```

and then when I am trying to put data in I am using reference the exact position in the 2d array I want to enter the data into e.g

```
addressData[0][0] = "String Data";
```

The program compiles yet when I run I get a NullPointerException error.
Am I using the wrong method to enter data into this 2d array?

Comment: Could you add more of your code?   Not a whole huge blort of it, just a small example which compiles and shows the behavior you're discussing.  Like "hello world", but with your String[][].

And remember your pre and code tags, please...

Comment: ok that's it running in a simple helloworld app

<pre>
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[][] addressData = null;

        addressData[0][0] = "Helloworld";
        
        System.out.println(addressData[0][0]);
    }
}
<code>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

String[][] addressData     - this is just declaration, you have to create actual object
String[][] addressData = new String[size][size];

Btw, There is no 2d arrays in java String[][] is an array of  arrays of strings

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I set a size to the 2d array it will work yet I don't want a limit on the size of the 2d array. It could range for just a few piece of data to thousands so I don't want a limit or null values. Is there any way around this?

Comment: If you don't want to fix the size, make it an array of Lists instead of a 2D-array.

Comment: @Student01: The only way around it is not using arrays. You can use a list of lists of strings.

Comment: As I wrote, it's not 2d array but array of arrays. You have to give a size when creating an array, so you have to do:

String[][] array = new String[Size][];   - it'll create an array of String[] type with length = size filled with nulls, but you can put arrays with different length into it, for example:
array[0] = new String[10];
array[1] = new String[50];

etc

Comment: ammoQ - you Can't make array of lists ( at least when using generics ). It's imposible to make an array of generic types

Comment: ok thanks for the help, I am going to try implementing a lit of string instead. Cheers